# laracasts/utilities When i use (use Javascript) of given library it only work in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am having trouble using the laracasts/utilities library with JavaScript. It seems to only work in Chrome, and when I try to fetch data in Laravel using Javascript::put, it only works in Chrome but not in other browsers. How can I use this function and fetch data in other browsers as well?

```
    JavaScript::put([
        'isPasswordRequired' => $isPasswordRequired,
    ]);
```